# Conditional coloring on spark RichText component

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have a spark RichText that I want to change his color according with the value on text property.

Negative values get red, positives blue...

When I declare the component, I call a method to set up the css style, but when the value changes, the color is not updated.

How can I put a conditional CSS Style?
Is possible to create custom skins to RichText component?

Thanks

---

Here is a example of my code:

```
<s:RichText id="txtOsc" styleName="{getCorOs(txtOsc.text)}" columnCount="1" kerning="on" text="10" whiteSpaceCollapse="preserve" x="460" y="103"/>

..
private function getCorOs(_text:String):String{
            if(_text.indexOf("-") > -1){                
                return "RED";
            }else{
                //positivo
                return "BLUE";
            }
        }
    ]]>
..
```

It creates ok, but if I change the value at runtime to -10, for instance, the color doesn't change.

Comment: Could you post an example of the code you've tried that isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-apply the new style: yourText.thePortionToColor.setStyle('color', 0xFFFFFF); or string value - it doesn't matter.
FTQuest